# can not create data file using code blocks

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

I've written a code to create a data file. In the if-else block the else block is executed but although the file is not created in the desired location. Why is it so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   FILE *fptr;

   fptr = fopen("C:\\test.txt", "w");
   if(fptr == NULL) // codition when file is not created
   {
       printf("File can not be created. \n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("file has been successfully created. \n");

   }
   //fputs(string, file_pointer_variable)
   fputs("my first write to file", fptr);
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to have rights to create a file in `c:\\`? Moreover if the creation fails you should terminate your program or avoid executing puts and so on

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the directory/location of the file and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, probably, belongs to permissions/rights on writing/creating a file in `c:\`

Your code must be changed to avoid using the file if the `fopen` failed, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
   FILE *fptr;

   fptr = fopen("C:\\test.txt", "w");
   if(fptr == NULL) // codition when file is not created
   {
       perror("fopen error: ");
       return 1;
   }
   else
   {
       printf("file has been successfully created. \n");
       fputs("my first write to file", fptr);
       fclose(fptr);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see I used [perror](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_perror.htm) that can add infos on error occurred with `fopen` function.